# What does some_name()->some_func() mean in PHP?

Tags: php

**What does some_name()->some_func() mean in PHP?**

I found something like this in a user controller method in a CodeIgniter application. I was wondering what that is and I couldn't find it anywhere. Code sample:

```
try
{
  Connect()->login($_POST);
}
  catch(Exception $e)
{
...
```

Comment: It's running a method off the returned object of another method. Maybe it's a singleton pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means `Connect()` returns an object, and you're calling the `login()` method of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Means what it means in a lot of other languages, execute some_name() to object returned by some_name() execute some_func().

In your example it means execute Connect() (which might be a Class constructor) and then execute login with the POST array.

Obviously one of those raises an exception.